# Laravel follower/following relationships

Tags: php, laravel, relationships

I am trying to make a simple follower/following system in laravel, nothing special, just click a button to follow or unfollow, and display the followers or the people following you.

My trouble is I can't figure out how to make the relationships between the models.

These are the migrations:

-User migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('gender');
        $table->date('dob');
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
```

-Followers migration:

```
Schema::create('followers', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('follower_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('following_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();        
    });
}
```

And here are the models:

-User model:

```
   class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Followers');
    }

}
```

-And the followers model is basically empty, this is where I got stuck

I tried something like this:

```
class Followers extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

but it didn't work.

Also, I'd like to ask if you could tell me how to write the "follow" and "display followers/following" functions. I've read every tutorial I could find but to no use. I can't seem to understand.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to realize that the "follower" is also a `App\User`. So you only need one model `App\User` with these two methods:

```
// users that are followed by this user
public function following() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'follower_id', 'following_id');
}

// users that follow this user
public function followers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'following_id', 'follower_id');
}
```

---

User `$a` wants to follow user `$b`:

```
$a->following()->attach($b);
```

User `$a` wants to stop following user `$b`:

```
$a->following()->detach($b);
```

---

Get all followers of user `$a`:

```
$a_followers = $a->followers()->get();
```

Comment: Oh my god! Thanks a million!

Comment: If you wanted to show the count of the followers could you use $a->followers()->get()->count()? or would I wrao the query into the count method?

Comment: @Martin Heralecký  you are champion!