# Laravel follower/following relationships -Profile to Profile naming convention

Tags: php, laravel, schema, relationship

I am trying to create a many to many following relationship in Laravel. So far all of the solutions, such as this one [Laravel follower/following relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913409/laravel-follower-following-relationships), I am finding are where a user can follow a profile. In my case a user can have many profiles so I want to make it so profiles can follow profiles.

I am new to Laravel and was told there is a naming convention. I created the migration with

```
php artisan make:migration creates_profile_profile_pivot_table --create profile_profile
```

And this is my schema

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profile_profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('profile_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('profile_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I get the error

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 duplicate column name: profile_id (SQL: create table "profile_profile" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "profile_id" integer not null, "profile_id" integer not null, "created_at" datetime null, "updated_at" datetime null))
```

If I replace the two profile_id's with following_id and follower_id will that clash with the naming convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way which you can follow the naming convention for this case: you must specify a different name for the second foreign key as you suggested.
This won't cause any problems, but when you will create the relations in the `Profile` model, you will have to specify the foreign keys manually, thing that Laravel will do automatically if you follow the convention.

Let's say that the other foreign key is called `follower_id`, the model relation will look like this:

```php
public function followers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Profile', 'profile_profile', 'profile_id', 'follower_id')->withTimestamps();
}
public function followed(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Profile', 'profile_profile', 'follower_id', 'profile_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Also** keep in mind that this is a `many to many` relation, and so in the migration you don't need `$table->bigIncrements('id');`, but you have to specify the primary key in this way:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profile_profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('profile_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('follower');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->primary(['profile_id', 'follower_id']);
        $table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')->on('profiles');
        $table->foreign('profile_id')->references('id')->on('profiles');
    });
}
```

Comment: so after `$table->primary(['profile_id', 'follower_id']);` Would the followee column look like1) `$table->unsignedBigInteger('profile_id');` or 2) `$table->unsignedBigInteger('profile_id', 'following_id');`

Comment: like what sorry?

Comment: Sorry, just fixed the comment still getting used to the markups

Comment: ok done, be sure that this migration runs after the create_profile_table migration, otherwise you will get an error like "can't add foreign key, table not found"

Comment: Worked great, had to change `"follower"` to `"follower_id"` on the second field. Thanks so much!